# Change python-gnupg lock file location?

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm trying to deploy a project which uses GPG to encrypt data being sent to a SOAP WebService.  When I tried to encrypt the file, I found that `python-gnupg` was trying to put a lock file into my `gnupghome` directory, which is not writable by the user Apache is run under.  I'd rather not give write access to "nobody", so is there a way to change the location python-gnupg uses to store lock files?

**Clarification:**
It was pointed out to me that I may not have made it clear that I am currently setting `gnupghome` when I initialize the object, but I do not want the lock files to be placed there, because I do not want "nobody" to have write access to that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock file is created by gnupg, not the python wrapper, and it is always created in the GNUPGHOME path, defaulting to `~/.gnupghome`.

You cannot prevent the lockfile, but you *can* set the directory to a temporary one. The disadvantage is that it'll not be able to load the default keyring so you'll need to pass it in explicitly, telling GNUPG to *ignore* the default file (it'll complain bitterly if you do not):

```
import tempfile
import shutil

home = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=home, keyring='/path/to/keyring/file',
        options=['--no-default-keyring'])
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(home)
```

In fact, I've gone a far as using a temporary file for the keyring as well; use the `tempfile.mkstemp()` function to create an empty file in the temporary directory generated above, import the key (drawn from a database) into that keyring (using `.import_keys()`) then use the imported key to do the encryption, before cleaning up the whole temporary home.

Comment: Is there a version requirement for `options`?  I keep being told:  `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'`

Comment: I see the `options` keyword argument was added in 0.3.1: http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/issues/detail?id=45 and http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/

Comment: Ok, manually upgraded to that since `easy_install` didn't seem to find it.  However, you don't need the options, specifying a `keyring` adds it automagically.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm not clear why would you need to use `mkstemp()` for a temporary keyring inside your `mkdtemp()`'d directory.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @zigg: My keyring is created to hold a key that is stored in the database. So when I encrypt, I need to create a temporary keyring to hold that key. There is no need to store that keyring permanently at all.

Comment: I get what you're doing; it just seems to me to involve unnecessary steps.  I can simply `mkdtemp()` a temporary `gnupghome` without creating a file for or specifying the keyring; `import_keys` will then create the default keyring files under that directory for me.

Comment: @zigg: right, but I don't want to rely on that; explicit is better than implicit, I don't want to have to think about the security implications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Python-GnuPG Getting Started](http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started) shows that you can set `gnupghome` like so:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/path/to/home/directory')
```

Comment: Yes, I set the `gpupghome` to the correct directory, but I do not want "nobody" to write to that directory.

Comment: So you want the lock files stored in a different directory from what `gnupghome` is set to?

Comment: Correct.  I'll make that more clear in the question, I thought I had gotten that across, but I will be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `python-gnupg` version 0.3.1 or above and thus have the `options` parameter, you can use this solution, provided the keyrings you need are readable:

```
>>> g = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/path/to/gnupghome', options=['--lock-never'])
```

I'm using this in a scenario where a verifying user has no write permissions to the `gnupghome` at all--just read permissions on `pubring.gpg` and `trustdb.gpg`:

```
>>> v = g.verify(open('message.gpg', 'r').read())
>>> v.valid
True
```